# Каким способом образовано слово "глубокий"?

Tags: словообразование

Каким способом образовано слово "глубокий"
Глубь + ок?

Comment: Посмотрите в словаре Тихонова, это непроизводное слово.  Глубь образуется усечением основы на ОК.

Comment: @Sharon почему основу слова путают с корнем?

Comment: Морфемный разбор слова (разбор слова по составу) начинается с выделения основы и формообразующих морфем — окончания и/или формообразующего суффикса (если они есть).  (Из учебника Литневской.)  В простом варианте: основа – это часть слова без окончания. В данном случае ГЛУБОК-  В родственных словах мы усекаем основу на ОК и добавляем другие суффиксы: глуб/ин/а.  В этом слове корень ГЛУБ- и суффикс ИН

Comment: Суффикс ОК в слове глубокий не выделяется.  Нельзя  выделять словоОБРАЗовательный суффикс в непроизводном слове, которое ни от чего не ОБРАЗовалось,

Answer (score 1):

ГЛУБО́КИЙ, -ая, -ое; -ок, -ока, -око и -око; глуб**же**; глубочайший. -Ожегов.

ГЛУБИНА, глубь, тамб. сиб. глыбь, вологодск. глуботина, стар. глубота ж. высота, вышина, в обратном смысле: протяжение по отвесу сверху вниз, от поверхности до дна.... . Глубокий, **глубкий**, **южн. глыбкий**, зап. глыбкой, далекий в глубину

Корень ГЛУБ +суффикс наречных прилагательных и наречий К/ОК: ловкий-ловок, мелкий мелок, глубкий/глыбкий-глубок. Дело в том, что **глыбок** стало существительным - маленькие глыбы, а прилагательное с -ок- осталось в форме глубок.

Насчет слова глыбкий - это от слова глыба, объемный то есть. Но дело в том, что глубина объема поверхностного не имеет, только скрытый под водой, то есть незримый объем, незримый предел, поэтому он постигаем только при условии погружения.

> "И еще дальше: к тому египетскому каменотесу, который выбирал для своих статуй непременно самый твердый материал, чтобы, не нарушая его глыбкости, придать ему то сильные, то нежные, но всегда простые формы. Таков Мандельштам." Из какой-то работы..

> Хуже нет на краю проживать. Как глыбкий снег, они меня обирают. Козольков — в полушубке, толсто подшитых валенках собачьей шапке.  Анатолий Ткаченко. Кони (1964)

> — Лезь, настилай! Пахнущая едким потом рослая фигура охотника Василия Зубцова соскользнула мимо Телегина с берега в воду. Иван Ильич увидел, как большая рука, дрожа, ухватилась за траву, отпустила ее и скрылась. — Глыбко, — зябким шепотом проговорил Зубцов откуда-то снизу. — Ребята, подавай доски... — Доски, доски давай! Неслышно и быстро, с рук на руки, стали подавать доски. Толстой.

> Через этот самый «пустяк» и с диомидом не пролезешь. Глыбко ушла жила... Должно полагать, спьяну наврал проклятый Кривушок, не тем будь помянут покойник. Мамин сибиряк.

> Вода в нем была вроде как бы и свойская: на вкус — пресная, на промер — не так уж глыбкая, по волне — не страшней той, что гуляла на озере Нево, а коли по рыбе считать — так и не хуже родной, ильменской. Соболев.

Глыбко - широко, далеко, объёмно относительно чего-то или к глубине воды, сильно, мощно.

> Дюже глыбко просадил он... — Глыбко?.. — переспросил барин. Успенский.

Можно еще подумать над Г в начале, так как в слове гладко-складный - слышится корень лад, но тут скорее всего г входит в состав корня, и глыб+а - это исходник, а вот глуб - это производная в сторону луб-руб - глубить-рубить...

Либо глубокий - это вообще другое слово, от слова голубой - цвет неба, глубокий как небо, подобный небу, высокий, беспредельный.

> Надобно думать, что желание проникнуть в глубокий мрак стольких протекших веков... Крылов.

> Ах, государь мой! вы тесните меня со всех сторон сильным образом, это глубокий и пространный океан трудностей, как испытать пути его, проходы, берега и пристани. Козельский.

> Я, будучи внезапу из глубокий печали в чрезмерную радость преселен, пребыл недвижим, точно воображая себе, что я, конечно, странствую во сновидениях. Н. И. Новиков. Живописец. Третье издание 1775 г. Часть II (1775)

То есть если смотреть по Нацкорпусу, первые упоминания слова глубокий, по крайней мере там, связаны не с физической глубиной - глыбкостью, а с переносным значением глубокий - высокий: *он - глубокий математик, глубокий мрак, глубокий сон, глубокий орган(звук органа)*. То есть глубокий применялось больше к предположению о чём-то, к восприятию чего-то, а не физическому статусу объекта. Глубокий относительно физических объектов начинает вероятно использовать Карамзин. Слова ГЛУБь и ГЛУБина встречаются в более ранних текстах довольно часто.

Кстати, слов выский тоже нет, как и выско, как и высже) - только выше из-за слияния звуков. Хотя корень очевидно высь.

Вот что пишет Дугин про этимологою слова глубина и я бы добавил ГЛУБь:

> Глубина — разделять
>
> От и.е ***glewbʰ**- родственное гр. Γλύφω (надрез, руна) отсюда иеро-глюфо
> и немецкое Kluft – расщелина.
>
> Греческое βυθός глубина – возможно от *dʰewbʰ- дно, славянское дно
> сюда же deep, tief
>
> ἄβυσσος ἀ- (a-) + βυθός (buthós, “depth of the sea”)
>
> grund – от и.е. *gʰrem-.
>
> Лат. profundus от и.е. *bʰudʰmḗn – отсюда же bottom, Ancient Greek
> πύνδαξ (púndax, “bottom”).
>
> Sanskrit बुध्न (budhna), — Ahi Budhnya Змей Бездн, персидское Persian
> بن (bon, “root, bottom”)
>
> Семитское омек עומק — عمق или мецулот מצולות
>
> Тюркское derin

Answer (score 1):

Слово **непроизводное**, однако выделяем в нем суффикс "ок", потому что у данного слова есть слова-родственники: ***глуб**-ин-а, у-**глуб**-и-ть-ся, **глуб**-ин-к-а.*
Замечу, что не существует чередования ***"ок/ноль звука"***.

---

Как известно каждому адекватному человеку, **корень - это общая часть всех родственных слов**, поэтому выделим в данном слове корень **"глуб"** и суффикс **"ок"** и не забудем указать, что данное слово ни от чего не образовано.

---

В доказательство привожу пример из словаря З. Потихи. Словарь Баранова разбирает слово ***"глубоководный"*** (родственное нашему слову) похожим образом: **глуб**-ок-о-вод-н-ый.

[image: глубокий]

Comment: Всем известно, как надо ПРАВИЛЬНО разбирать это слово, наприме:  https://kartaslov.ru/разбор-слова-по-составу/глубокий  (У Потихи  субморфное разделение на морфемы.) Во всех производных словах (глубина) выделяется корень ГЛУБ.  А непроизводное слово не надо делить на части.  Литневская:  Словообразующие некорневые морфемы служат для образования новых слов

Comment: Я думала, вы поправите по Литневской. Это странно: слово непроизводное (ни от чего не образовалось), а вы выделяете в нем словообразовательный суффикс. Это как?  Хотела как лучше...

Comment: А это формообразующий суффикс (тематическая гласная), а не словообразовательный. Кстати, привет Славе.

Comment: Ну, тематическая гласная (надо уточнить), но уж в любом случае не словообразовательный.

Comment: Никто не говорил, что он словообразующий, но он должен выделяться, потому что такой корень сохраняется в других словах.

Comment: Никому он не должен. Это не морфема.  Тематические суффиксы https://studall.org/all3-8574.html

Comment: @Sharon словообразование в данном случае никакой роли не играет: что происходит со словом в ходе образования новых слов - это лишь особенности  словообразовательной системы русского языка, не более. Корень при всем при этом остается одинаковым, если это не историческое чередование.

Comment: Разумеется, корень здесь ГЛУБ, он получается при усечении основы и потом участвует в образовании других слов.  Но ОК —  не морфема, так как морфемами считаются словообразовательные суффиксы. Морфемный анализ —  это разделение на морфемы.  Это всё определения, если вы согласны с ними. Поэтому в непроизводном слове мы не выделяем ОК. Усечение основы — распространенное явление.  Просто в языке существует суффикс ОК вообще, но здесь его нет.

Comment: @Sharon, увидел в комментариях выше вот это: «А это формообразующий суффикс (тематическая гласная), а не словообразовательный. Кстати, привет Славе». О чём там шла речь? Я где-то в чём-то был не прав?

Comment: Я не поняла, зачем в той теме вы упоминаете  глагол "играть". В слове "крепостной" минимальным формантом является креп-, хотя в разных источниках выделяется корень крепост-, крепостн-. Здесь приходится выбирать один из вариантов. В глагол "играть" такого выбора нет,  игр-  считается корнем во всех словарях. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: @Sharon Ну, наверное, вместо «играть» мне следовало бы привести какой-либо другой пример. И всё же:  на основании чего можно утверждать, что «а» здесь – тематическая гласная, а не часть корня – как, к примеру, «а» в «дать»?  Ведь во всех формах глагола «играть» это «а» присутствует: _играл, играю, игравший…_   Я это без всякого подвоха спрашиваю, мне действительно интересно, можно ли, не сравнивая «играть» со словами, образованными от «играть», найти ответ, какой корень в этом слове?

Comment: По ссылке https://studall.org/all3-8574.html : Глагольные тематические гласные – показатели морфологического класса глаголов, поэтому глагол неудобен в качестве примера. Сравнить:  видеть,  тематический гласный Е не во всех формах.

Answer (score 1):

**ГЛУБОКИЙ**

Слово **непроизводное**.

При морфемном членении этого слова практически все известные мне словаристы (Потиха, Панов и Текучев, Морковкин, Николина…) выделяют в нём связанный корень ***глуб-*** (ср.: ***глуб**-ина*, *за-**глуб**-ить*…), суффикс ***-ок-***, окончание ***-ий***.

Суффикс ***-ок-*** помимо прилагательного ***глубокий*** встречается в русском языке ещё в четырёх прилагательных:

***далёкий, высокий, широкий, одинокий***.

См. [**Зализняк А.А. Труды по акцентологии. Том 1**]:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Называют ***-ок-*** в этих прилагательных суффиксом и **школьные пособия.**

Из справочника [**Баранов М.Т. Русский язык. Справочные материалы : Пособие для учащихся общеобразовательных учреждений** / М.Т. Баранов, Т.А. Костяева, Прудникова А.В.; под ред. Н.М. Шанского. — М., 2011]:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]